# Bigquery Select in Array

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, flatten, unnest

My schema
[image]

how i´ll access the "event_params.key" at de where clause and how i get de value of array in string_value, int_value or float_value.

LIKE

```
SELECT 
  timestamp AS data,
  event_name AS event,
  event_params.key AS key,
  event_params.value AS value
FROM `instance_name.dt_name.db_name` 
WHERE
  event_params.key["KEYNAME"] = "VALUE-STRING_VALUE"
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the data.
Do you want to keep only the right keys?
If you want to see all keys for a dataset if one key fits, please see the commented out sample below.

```sql
With tbl as 
(select current_timestamp() as timestamp, "test" as event_name,
[struct( "KEYNAME" as key, 
struct("VALUE-STRING_VALUE" as string_value, null as int_value, null as float_value) as value
),
struct("another_key",struct(null,1,1.0))
] as event_params
union all select current_timestamp() as timestamp, "no" as event_name,
[struct("another_key",struct("",1,1.0))]
)

SELECT 
  timestamp AS data,
  event_name AS event,
  ep.key AS key,
  ep.value AS value,
ifnull(EP.value.string_value,''||ifnull(EP.value.int_value,EP.value.float_value)) as value_,

FROM tbl,unnest (event_params) ep
WHERE
  ep.key="KEYNAME" and  ep.value.string_value= "VALUE-STRING_VALUE"
ORDER BY timestamp ASC


/*
SELECT 
  timestamp AS data,
  event_name AS event,
  event_params
FROM tbl
WHERE
 (( Select max(ep.value.string_value="VALUE-STRING_VALUE") from unnest (event_params) ep where ep.key="KEYNAME"  ))
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
*/
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked!

how could i join all values ​​of "value" into one?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/inUJH.png

Comment: ```SELECT 
timestamp AS date,
event_name AS event,
EP.key AS key,
CASE 
  WHEN EP.value.string_value IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(EP.value.string_value AS STRING)
  WHEN EP.value.int_value IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(EP.value.int_value AS STRING)
  WHEN EP.value.float_value IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(EP.value.float_value AS STRING)
END AS value,
FROM tbl,
UNNEST(event_params) AS EP,```